# Eigenvalues (or lack thereof) of $A$ for $A^2 = -I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm just starting with Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors and it all seemed to be going fine until this question stumped me:

> Let A be a $2\times 2$ matrix for which $A^2=-I$. 
>  Prove that A has no real Eigenvalues.

I tried using the fact that it'd have a determinant of $1$ whereas any eigenvalue would have to be the result of a homogenous equation, but apparently that rule only applies in the other direction.

I tried using the fact that any matrix that multiplied by itself would be of rank $2$ couldn't have an eigenvalue because that would require it to be of rank $1$ or less (for there to be non-trivial solutions to the typical polynom) but apparently that's wrong, because I later have to prove that A is similar to $\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{smallmatrix} \right)$ which is of rank $2$, so that doesn't hold up.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go back to the definition: if $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$, then $A x = \lambda x$. Now $A^2 x = \lambda^2 x$. This gives $\lambda^2 = -1$, contradiction!

Comment: Golly it seems so simple now I feel ashamed having asked it in the first place. I guess I was off looking for zebras where there was just a simple ol' horse. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. What is $A^2 v$?